# Android code about timer

Tags: android

I have change code to below and my purpose is to set a button 
when I click the timer run,how to change the code below? thanks
new code below

I have change code to below and my purpose is to set a button 
when I click the timer run,how to change the code below? thanks
new code below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Handler aHandler;
    TextView aTextView;
    Button  aButton;
    EditText aEditText;
    Handler aHandler01;
    TextView aTextView01;
    Button  aButton01;
    EditText aEditText01;
    Boolean checker=false;
    int count = 11;
    int count01 = 11;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText01);
        aTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        aEditText01 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText02);
        aTextView01 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        aButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
        aButton01=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button02);
  //第一個計時器

        aButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){ if(!aEditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {count=Integer.parseInt(aEditText.getText().toString());}
                aHandler = new Handler();

                if(checker==false){

                    aHandler.post(runnable);
                    checker=true;
                    }
            }
        });
//第二個計時器
        aButton01.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!aEditText01.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    count01 = Integer.parseInt(aEditText01.getText().toString());
                }
                aHandler01 = new Handler();
                aHandler01.post(runnable01);
            }
        });




    }

    //第一個計時器
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (count> 0) {
                aTextView.setText(Integer.toString(count-1));
                count--;
                aHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            }else{
                aTextView.setText("boom");
            }
        }
    };
    //第二個計時器
    final Runnable runnable01 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (count01> 0) {
                aTextView01.setText(Integer.toString(count01-1));
                count01--;
                aHandler01.postDelayed(runnable01, 1000);
            }else{
                aTextView01.setText("boom");
            }
        }
    };



        @Override
    protected void onPause() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (aHandler != null) {
            aHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any Exception ? Please post your LogCat outputs

Comment: At the very beginning I have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
    Boolean checker=false;
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText01);
        aTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        aButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
        aButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){ if(!aEditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {count=Integer.parseInt(aEditText.getText().toString());}



 if(!checker){
             checker=true;
            handler.post(runnable);//to start timer


            }


            }
        });



    }



    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


  if(checker)
    {
    checker=false;
     return;
    }
                if (count> 0) {
                    aTextView.setText(""+Integer.toString(count-1));
                    count--;
                    aHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                }else{
                    aTextView.setText("boom");
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74957/discussion-on-answer-by-karthika-pb-android-code-about-timer).

Answer (score 0):

as you are assigning the value to 'count' variable in OnCreate from editText when editText is empty, it is returning null string which then you are parsing for int value which returns NumberFormatException

try to do it as follows

```
if (!aEditText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        count = Integer.parseInt(aEditText.getText().toString());
    }
```

OR you can assign a value to 'count' from editText on any button's click or using TextChangedListener(TextWatcher) to monitor and get text from edittext at run time.

Comment: When I replace       //   count=Integer.parseInt(aEditText.getText().toString());
    }